# Is whom actually a word?

Tags: word-usage

I research up the word "whom" but, the internet keeps changing it to "who". So, I wanted to confirm if whom is a actual word. For example, before I search up "whom" and the internet asked me do you mean who?

Comment: Forget the "internet". Try a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, it's a real world. No, you almost never *have* to use it.

Comment: Can you please explain what you did to research the term "whom"? What did you actually do?

Comment: Maybe more to the point, what do you mean "the Internet keeps changing it"? I am rather puzzled. Every single word I type shows up on the Internet exactly as I typed it. That's why YouTube looks the way it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word [“whom”](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825043658/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/who-or-whom) is an objective pronoun of who.

In practice, most people never use whom like this in speech because it sounds extremely formal. They don't use whom at all, and instead use who in all contexts, i.e.:

1. Who do you think we should support?
2. Who do you wish to speak to?

a) Whom do you think we should support? [here, whom is the object of support]

b) To whom do you wish to speak? [here, whom is following the preposition to]